# transform xml using excel vba code (xpath2.0,xslt2.0)

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xslt

I have requirement to transform the xml file by passing xslt using excel vba code.
i have tried with some sample code its working for simple xslt.
When i started testing with complex one.Got error distinct-values(//object/@name) is not supporting.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//object" group-by="@name">
  <object><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></object>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

just wanted to confirm . Is Microsoft Excel VBA is supporting Xpath2.0 and XSLT2.0. If not what is the alternate solution for this.

Your help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The XSLT 1.0 method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: No, it's highly unlikely that XSLT 2.0 is supported. The simplest way to find out is to _test_ it - try to transform a stylesheet that contains an XPath 2.0 function, e.g. `tokenize()`. The XSLT 1.0 solution is to use a _key_.

Comment: VBA and Excel are Microsoft products. Microsoft at this time only has implementations of XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

> Is Microsoft Excel VBA is supporting Xpath2.0 and XSLT2.0.

**No**, VBA and Excel are Microsoft products. Microsoft at this time only has implementations of XSLT 1.0.

> If not what is the alternate solution for this.

**A good and efficient XSLT 1.0 solution is to use the** **[Muenchian Method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).**

Comment: which technology will support XSLT2.0 and Xpath 2.0. Requirement is to make an automation between xml and xslt. If any error i have to send to user.

Comment: @Deepaksingh, Something non-Microsoft. Saxon is written in Java, and there is a version for ,NET, but I doubt you will be able to make a COM object of it. Do try XML-SPY, but the latest version, I think, don't offer free, community components.